# Let G be an abelian group. Let V be an irreducible faithful CG-module. Prove that dimV = 1 and G is cyclic.

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, vector-spaces, representation-theory, cyclic-groups

I was wondering if I could get some help with the following problem. I know how to prove it with Schur's Lemma but I'm having problems without it.

Let G be an abelian group. Let V be an irreducible faithful CG-module. Prove that dimV = 1 and G is cyclic without using Schur's Lemma.

Comment: But $G=({\mathbb C} \setminus \{0\},\times)$ has such a representation and it is not cyclic.

Comment: Sorry G is assumed to be finite.

Comment: In that case you can find a common eigenvector of a set of generators of $G$ giving ${\rm dim }V = 1$, and then $G$ is a finite subgroup of ${\mathbb C}^*$ and hence cyclic.

Comment: Ok, so I think that I first have to show that for every element of the group there is a subspace of dimension 1. Then I need to show that vg spans V, but how would I go about doing this?

Comment: JackWo, why did you delete [the question leading up to this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1393185/11619) (link viewable only to 10k+ users). The same [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1399276/11619) - the question discussing the non-triviality of the intersection of the zero sum submodule and the span of the all ones vector? If I were a cynic I might think that you want to cover your tracks or something. More likely it is a new user's partial shame reaction (which is nothing to worry about).